# good way to implement a z-buffer

Tags: 3d, rendering, love2d, zbuffer

currently I'm making my first experiences with 3D projection and rendering.
So, I'm using löve lua (ik, not the best platfrom for 3D), and I can render all polygons (only triangles) perfectly. Because sorting the table of polygons by distance to the camera is the task, that takes the most time, I'm implementing a z-buffer for this. But I'm not quite sure how to do this. I know the principles, but how do I find out the distance of a point in a triangle to the camera position?
My current solution sounds like this:

```
translate edge points of the triangle to 2D points ->
create polygon of those ->
for every pixel in the polygon: ->
translate 2D point back to 3D vertex (somehow) ->
calculate distance of vertex to camera position ->
if distance is bigger than zbuffer entry, overwrite zbuffer entry and 
set pixel to polygon color
```

This sounds really inefficient. How can I speed this up? Does anyone here have a better way to implement zbuffering?

Comment: I presume by love you mean love2d, if not can remove that tag

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to implement a software Z-Buffer you don't need to sort the polygons, Only those that have alpha blending and can't be included in [Z-Buffer technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering).

Once you have translated vertices into camera space ([using view matrix calculations](http://schabby.de/view-matrix/)) you will have the detph Z values for each vertex, then it comes the [polygon rasterization](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lets-build-a-3d-graphics-engine-rasterizing-triangles-and-quads--gamedev-8852)  that finally give you the Z depth for each pixel.

Now is the time for Z test every time you write a pixel in the screen; If the pixel are in front of current pixel, then write, else do nothing.

Performance notes: 
 -Remember you don't need to sort polygons when using Z-Buffer
 -Be careful when you say "distance of vertex to camera position".. DO NOT make any *distance* calculation, matrix transformation will give you the values you need much more efficiently.